# Jquery auto-complete fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

Site: login.live.com
I want to on the mail service to automate the login and password. Do this:

```
$('[name=loginfmt]').val(mail);
$('[name=passwd]').val(pass);
$('#idSIButton9').click();
```

I do it in the browser console. But the site thinks that we do not press the keys. How is it to emulate?

P.S. Does not work!

```
$('[name=loginfmt]').keydown();
$('[name=loginfmt]').keypress();
$('[name=loginfmt]').keyup();
$('[name=loginfmt]').blur();
```

Comment: My 2ct: Get a browser with a proper password manager, then you don't need stuff like this ...

Comment: the site has jquery? Any errors in the console? Is this code executing before the DOM or jQuery is loaded?

Comment: I need it for my project. Yes, the site supports jquery and field filled. But not sent

Comment: Check my answere below, you code is fine you just need jQuery on that page or do it using simple JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

if you really wanna do something like that then be aware that there is no jQuery on that page and still you can do what you want.

Step 1 : Add jQuery to the page using JavaScript

Step 2,3,4..... : Do what you were doing using jQuery.

```
var script=document.createElement('script');
script.type='text/javascript';
script.src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js';

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Comment: I have the embed jquery on this page

Comment: Your code is working fine for me after adding jQuery on page.

Comment: And when you press send, the data is sent or displayed an error when manually fill in the fields?